# Troubles with connectionParams in graphql-mesh

Tags: graphql, graphql-ws, graphql-mesh

I'm having troubles with the newest version of graphql-mesh and subscriptions. I'm receiving wrong data in my connectionParams. This is a part of my .yaml file:

```
handler:
      graphql:
          endpoint: ${CHATS_ENDPOINT}
          subscriptionsEndpoint: ${CHATS_SUBSCRIPTIONS_ENDPOINT}
          subscriptionsProtocol: WS
          operationHeaders:
                    Authorization: "{context.headers['authorization']}"
          connectionParams:
                    Authorization: "{context.headers['authorization']}"
      multipart: true
```

I expect receive this object on connectionParams: {authorization: "value of this variable"}.  In place of that I'm receiving this literal string: "{context.headers['authorization']}". I tried too with "{context.connectionParams['authorization']}", but the result is the same.

I'm using this version of the packages (the newest version of everything):

```
 "@graphql-mesh/cli": "0.88.4",
 "@graphql-mesh/graphql": "0.96.2",
 "@graphql-mesh/runtime": "0.97.3",
 "@graphql-mesh/store": "0.96.2",
 "@graphql-mesh/utils": "0.96.2",
 "graphql": "15.8.0"
```

What could be happening?